# Property file not being read from jar

Tags: java

I have a simple maven project that reads properties from src/main/resources, and runs perfectly fine in eclipse, but when I export this application as a runnable jar although it tells me `Exporting resources/test.properties` while building the jar, it breaks unless I include the test.properties file in the location I am invoking my shell script from. Why does this happen? How does it work fine in eclipse? When I look into the jar file contents, it is exactly in the same folder - resources, but command line is just not working. Any advise?

Here is the code that reads the properties from the file -

```
public class Test {
    private static Properties properties = new Properties();

    static{
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
            if(is!=null)
            properties.load(is);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new TestException("Unable to load the properties file :" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        }
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key){
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue){
        return properties.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
    }
```

To get any property, I invoke the getProperty  method.

Comment: show the code which loads the file

Comment: What does exactly mean `not working`? Probably you have another `/test.properties` coming from another jar? The name is too common.

Comment: When I print the values I am reading from the file, all are coming up as null when I execute from command line. In eclipse it works fine. I am building the jar fine as far as I know. For the record, I changed the name of the file to an obscure name. That didn't help either.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, right. I think Eclipse builds the .jar incorrectly. In maven all files in `src/main/resources/*` are packaged into `/*`, but you are saying that your jar has the file as `/resources/test.properties`, and the `getResourceAsStream("test.properties")` expects the file in the root folder, not inside `/resources`. This is wrong. Use maven to build .jar.

Comment: This does not make sense. If it is working in eclipse, why wouldn't it work when I run from command line? I understand getResourceAsStream reads from root folder, but in eclipse, I don't have this file in my root folder. It is clearly reading from resources.

Comment: Edit - getResourceAsStream reads from classpath, not root folder.

Comment: @rickygrimes I mean root folder of classpath (or of a jar archive), not root folder of your hard drive obviously.

Comment: @rickygrimes Maybe Eclipse makes something wrong while building .jar, but works correctly while running from IDE. You are saying `it is exactly in the same folder - resources` - and this is wrong, it should be at the top level.